# bidirectional binding spring (work in one way) or cache

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, data-binding

i'm working on a project in Spring using Spring MVC, bootstrap, Hibernate, Jsp .

When i delete an Employe and i refresh the page it appears in the page even that it is deleted from DB.

Is it the problem of bidirectional binding i guess or cache ?

**notes :**
*i'm using Singleton*

```
/**
 * @see com.my.dao.EmployeDao#deleteEmploye(int)
 */
@Override
public void deleteEmploye(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Employe dept = (Employe) session.load(Employe.class, id);
    session.delete(dept);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

**can someone help?**

Comment: Have you ever looked at JPA? I think you should look at that, it will reduce a lot of the boilerplate code, especially simple stuff like this. There is also a Spring Data Rest which you can use as well. Here's a link to the Spring site Data JPA : http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

Comment: remove the lines session.BeginTranasaction and last line. Next, don't load the object, get the object. So you must write session.get(Employee.class, id);. Please refactor your Employe class so its named Employee, with 2 e's. Also, it is more useful to see how you are loading the class, you should put some class information as well.

Comment: Just one more thing. After calling session.delete(dept), call session.flush();